# Weex keep app running in background

Tags: plugins, service, background, weex

I want to make an alarm app using weex. However I guess I will need a service that will run in the background.

How can I do it using weex? Is there something ready for this like a plugin or so?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. you need write custom module to support this.

iOS doc: http://weex.apache.org/references/advanced/extend-to-ios.html

android doc: http://weex.apache.org/references/advanced/extend-to-android.html

Comment: Thanks Neeo, it would be nice if weex had something similar to cordova plugins repositories.